# how to decode objects in NSmutablearray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I am creating a SQLite database.

To get data from the table I am using this code in `appdelegate.m` class:

```
-(void) readItemsFromDatabaseforTable:(NSString *)tableName {
    // Setup the database object
    sqlite3 *database;

    // Init the animals Array
    itemsList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Open the database from the users filessytem
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
        NSString *sql_str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from %@", tableName];

        const char *sqlStatement = (char *)[sql_str UTF8String];
        NSLog(@"query %s",sqlStatement);
        //const char *sqlStatement = "select * from allcategories" ;
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                // Read the data from the result row
                NSString *aName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
                NSInteger aDescription =(compiledStatement, 2);
                //  NSString *aImageUrl = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];

                // Create a new animal object with the data from the database

                Category *item = [[Category alloc] initWithName:aName Quantity:aDescription];

                // Add the animal object to the animals Array
                [itemsList addObject:item];

                [item release];
            }
        }
        // Release the compiled statement from memory
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

    }
    sqlite3_close(database);

}
```

I am getting this array in `viewcontroller.m` class like this:

```
MyGroceryListAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyGroceryListAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSLog(@"%@",appDelegate.itemsList);
```

It displays output like this:

```
(
    "<Category: 0x6b355d0>",
    "<Category: 0x6b356e0>",
    "<Category: 0x6b35790>",
    "<Category: 0x6b35830>",
    "<Category: 0x6b358d0>",
    "<Category: 0x6b35980>",
)
```

How can I convert this to normal array?

Comment: is there any reason you are using sqlite instead of core data? It is very rarely the right choice.(nothing to say it is the wrong choice in this instance.)

Comment: I was just curious as to what your reasons were. Is it remote db or personal preference? Hope my answer helps anyway.

Comment: Only masochists use the SQLite C API in Objective-C.  [Use FMDB](http://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) or [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could post the header for the Category object it would give us more to go on. but you would probably want to implement the description method on it.

```
-(NSString *)description{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name:%@ Quantity:%i",self.name,self.quantity];
}
```

Comment: (I fixed your method case; +1 though.)